# Redirect with Component Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

On React, I'm trying to redirect to a page, and have the main component update.

With `<Redirect push to ="…" />`, the component gets rerendered, but `ComponentDidUpdate` is not called.

I'm also trying to switch from `<Redirect>` to `this.setState(…)`, but this doesn't change my URL.

Do you know of any workarounds?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post your code, where you are trying to `this.setState`

Comment: Hi Aaqib. I'm trying to reload the parent component. I have an onclick function on a child component, that when activated, runs `setState` in the parent component.
Before, I had the `<Redirect>` being returned in the render() method of the child component.

Comment: it will be really helpful if i can see the code